# Close menu on mouseLeave

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on this project where navigation menu auto opens on hover but It doesn't auto close when I move mouse cursor.

Here is my code, correct where I am wrong.

```
jQuery(document).on('hover', '.mobile-sub-menu-controller', function () {
       jQuery(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideFadeToggle('return-position', 400);

        if (jQuery(this).find('i').hasClass('icon-angle-down')) {
            jQuery(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-angle-down');
            jQuery(this).find('i').addClass('icon-angle-up');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-angle-up');
            jQuery(this).find('i').addClass('icon-angle-down');
        }
    });
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example through `mouseover` and `mouseleave`

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.mobile-sub-menu-controller', function () {
       $(this).find('.sub-menu').stop().slideDown('fast');
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.mobile-sub-menu-controller', function () {
       $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideUp('fast');
});
```

```css
.mobile-sub-menu-controller{
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.sub-menu{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mobile-sub-menu-controller'>
  open menu
  <ul class='sub-menu'>
    <li>menu item1
    <li>menu item2
    <li>menu item3
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mouseenter` instead of hover, and `mouseleave` when you leave this block

Answer (score 0):

Use the alias syntax:

```
jQuery(document).on('hover', '.mobile-sub-menu-controller', function () {
     // enter code here
    },function(){
     // exit/mouse leave code here
});
```

OR the direct events:

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseenter', '.mobile-sub-menu-controller', function ()       {
     // enter code here
    });
jQuery(document).on('mouseleave', '.mobile-sub-menu-controller',,function(){
     // exit/mouse leave code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my problem too. There's very simple way for menu bar.
HTML:

```
<ul class="menubar">
    <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li class="menuitem haschild">
        <a href="#">services</a>
        <div class="submenu">
            <a>Back-end</a>
            <a>Front-end</a>
        </div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(document).on('mouseover','li.menuitem.haschild',function(){
        $(this).children().slideDown();
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave','li.menuitem.haschild',function(){
        $(this).children(".submenu").slideUp();
    });
});
```

Note: As you know, The ".submenu" elements have to be `display:none` in CSS. Also it must be `position:absolute` to show below/beside of parent menu.